# Какой корень в слове "приступить"

Tags: морфемика

Мне кажется, что должен быть **"приступ"**, т.к.  слово имеет значение "начинать что-то делать" и не связано с процессом ходьбы.

Comment: https://razbiraem-slovo.ru/po-sostavu/приступить  Это морфемный разбор по формально-структурному принципу (Тихонов).  Семантика не учитывается. У глагола есть своя словарная статья (это семантика). ПРИСТУПИТЬ, -ступлю, -ступишь; св. 1. обычно к чему. Начать что-л., приняться за что-л. П. к делу, к работе. П. к уборке. П. к чтению. П. к докладу.

Comment: То есть тут есть приставка?

Comment: Да, есть. Формально-структурный разбор не учитывает словообразование, а основан на "узнаваемости" морфем.  Мы понимаем значение приставки ПРИ и корня СТУП в современном языке и выделяем их.

Comment: не начинать что-то делать, а подойти к границе чего-то - при+ступить. Вы путаете причину и следствие, когда ориентируйтесь на базарную семантику. У слова есть логика словообразования, вы же пользуетесь не логикой, а знанием употребления слова в определенных ситуация, то есть исходите из функционала, а не причины, ваша семантика вторична к логике словообразования. Сегодня вы помните это, завтра забудете, но слово от этого не меняется, потому что дело в смысле и логике, а не в каком-то условном значении набора букв. Приступ - борьба у границ крепости, а не начало сражения.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто корень "приступ" выделить?

Comment: Потому что это не корень

Comment: Приступ - корень - приступ. Приступить - корень - ступ. Чего непонятного?

Comment: @user190920 Приступ тоже корень ступ.

Comment: @Sharon Шерон. А можете свой вариант разбора написать (все возможные варианты, если есть).

Comment: Я не видела словарей  с другим разбором – вероятно,  других вариантов нет.  ПРИСТУПИТЬ, 1. обычно к чему. НАЧАТЬ что-л., приняться за что-л. П. к делу, к работе.   Считается, что приступить – это как бы подойти К НАЧАЛУ. Здесь нужно смотреть словообразовательный разбор. У Тихонова: ступить – приступить, тогда корень СТУП.   Если бы слово в других словарях имело свою словообразовательную цепочку, то можно было бы выделить корень ПРИСТУП-.  Но и этой информации нет. Кроме того, словообразовательный разбор не всегда учитывается при морфемном разборе.

Comment: Поэтому вряд ли можно найти источник с корнем «приступ» (при морфемном разборе).

Comment: Ступить-приступить (вполне вероятно, что имеется в виду основное значение, а не "начать").

Comment: Татьяна Алексеевна: «_Ступить-приступить (вполне вероятно, что имеется в виду основное значение, а не "начать")_.» === Я предвидел такое сомнение с Вашей стороны, потому и сослался в своём ответе не на «Словообразовательный словарь» **Тихонова**, а на **его же** «Морфемно-орфографический словарь», где корень «ступ» выделен именно в слове «**Приступить**» со значением «**начать**».

Answer (score 2):

> **Какой корень в слове "приступить"?**
>
> Мне кажется, что должен быть "приступ", т.к. слово имеет значение
> "начинать что-то делать" и не связано с процессом ходьбы.

**Корень – это общая часть родственных слов.**

У слова ***приступить*** со значением *Начать что-л., приняться за что-л.* в современном русском языке есть близкое по семантике слово [***подступить***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), описание в словарях одного из значений которого совпадает почти дословно с описанием слова *приступить*:

> 6. *Разг.* Перейти к чему-л., приняться за что-л. *К этой проблеме надо п. осторожно.*

Общую часть этих родственных слов — ***приступить*** и ***подступить*** — и следует считать их корнем: ***ступ***.

Такой корень выделяется в слове ***приступить*** и во всех известных мне морфемных словарях.

См., к примеру, [**Тихонов «Морфемно-орфографический словарь русского языка**]:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, какому словарю соответствует такой разбор?  Спасибо.

Comment: Подступить и приступить, по-моему, разные смыслы имеют. Приступить - начать, подступить - найти подходящее решение.Разве можно сопоставлять разные по смыслу слова?

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна: «_Разве можно сопоставлять разные по смыслу слова?_». === Разные — конечно нельзя! Но я постарался подобрать для сравнения в своём ответе слово, наиболее близкое по семантике к «приступить». Вот как описывает значения этих слов **Кузнецов** в своём толковом словаре: **ПРИСТУПИТЬ**… 1… Начать что-л., **приняться за что-л.**

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Comment: **ПОДСТУПИТЬ**… 6… Перейти к чему-л., **приняться за что-л.**

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C